# Evenly Matched and Cosmic Cyclone

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I had a question regarding a unique trap called [Evenly Matched](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Evenly_Matched):

> At the end of the Battle Phase, if your opponent controls more cards than you do, make your opponent banish cards face-down until they control the same number of cards. If you control no cards, you can activate this card from your hand.

And a powerful Quick-play spell called [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone):

> Pay 1000 LP, then target 1 Spell/Trap card and remove it from play.

Now the thing is. I was dueling a True Draco deck the other day with my Blue Eyes. I was trying to play [Trade-In](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Trade-In) and my opponent activated [Imperial Order](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Order). As he did so, I chained [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone) to remove it from play before it's effect resolved. Now basically it went like this:

- Chain 1: [Trade-In](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Trade-In)
- Chain 2: [Imperial Order](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Order)
- Chain 3: [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone)

Chain 3 resolves first, then chain 2 (but since it's removed from play it doesn't resolve), then chain 1.

So basically given that my [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone) was able to stop [Imperial Order](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Order)'s effect from resolving, could [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone) also be chained to [Evenly Matched](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Evenly_Matched) and stop IT from resolving it's effect?

Answer (score 4):

> So basically given that my Cosmic Cyclone was able to stop Imperial Order's effect from resolving, could Cosmic Cyclone also be chained to Evenly Matched and stop IT from resolving it's effect?

**No you can't**

The thing is that you were able to prevent Imperial Order from resolving its effect because it is a Continuous Trap card. **In Yu-Gi-Oh some cards need to remain face-up to resolve their effects; continuous spell and trap cards are one of those** (field cards also).

This means that you can "negate" (do note that you are *not* negating, but instead preventing from resolving) cards like [Fire Formation - Tenki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Formation_-_Tenki) with cards like Cosmic Cyclone or the classic Mystical Space Typhoon.

The thing is that **Evenly Matched is not a continuous card** so even though it is banished or in the GY when resolving it will resolve, as you did not negate it's activation.

A common example (and mistake) similar to this is when unexperienced players think they can *"negate Dark Hole with Mystical Space Typhoon"*, when you can't as Dark Hole is not continuous and MST does not negate.

Comment: well that's a darn shame. What about Parthian Shot? Whenever the Battle Phase ends, the turn automatically ends. Would that stop Evenly Matched since it can only activated at the end of the Battle Phase?

Comment: @Therationalduelist if Evenly Matched's effect was already activated then using Parthian Shot will have no effect, as it does not negate Evenly Matched. Firsly because Evenly Matched effect is mandatory, so it activates first during the end of the BP, you can chain to that Parthian Shot, but what will happen is that (in reverse order): It becomes the end phase, and then the banish takes place.

Comment: Man this game is so strange....

Comment: @Therationalduelist LOL... and there are stranger games...  but in general I thing that YGO is quite logical, the complex part are the chaining and precedence of activations, and also details like the continuous cards, etc. To be honest learning all these took me a while, and a lot of trial and error and misuse of some effects (which I eventually learned out to use properly). What I suggest is that you get involved in official tournaments more often, to get a feel and know of the level competitive play requires.

Comment: @Therationalduelist random card that came to mind worth checking: [Pitch-Black Warwolf](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Pitch-Black_Warwolf). Other that can help you against Evenly Matched, besides a MST lol, is [Trap Stun](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Trap_Stun). But bottom line, MST is a Staple Card for a reason, I always include at least one copy in my decks, even though there were other cards or monsters that can destroy spell traps (in case their effs are negated). Nothing beats the good ol' MST :) (I love it so much mine is a Ultra Rare, First Edition, from Magic Ruler)

Comment: Pitch-Black Werewolf wouldn't stop Evenly Matched because Evenly matched activates at the END of the Battle Phase.

Comment: @Therationalduelist yes, but it is *still* the BP. In other words, it is not during main phase 2. The end of the BP is when no further attacks can or want to be declared.

Comment: 'Parthian Shot' wouldn't work because it doesn't end the battle phase, after the battle phase it becomes the end phase. If it actually changed the what phase it was in during resolution something like 'It is now the end phase' then I believe it would stop 'Evenly Matched' because the 'At the end of the battle phase' is both a condition of activation and resolution.

Comment: The Dark Hole example is really good!