# Can I resolve this effect that has been destroyed, banished, or sent to the deck?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

## Scenario 1:

I activate "[XYZ Effect](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Xyz_Effect)". My opponent activates [Mystical Space Typhoon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mystical_Space_Typhoon). XYZ Effect is destroyed. Does XYZ Effect resolve?

## Scenario 2:

I activate "[XYZ Effect](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Xyz_Effect)". My opponent activates [Cosmic Cyclone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_Cyclone). XYZ Effect is banished after he pays 1000LP. Is "[XYZ Effect](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Xyz_Effect)" resolved?

## Scenario 3:

I activate "[XYZ Effect](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Xyz_Effect)" My opponent activates a card that returns my card to the deck. Is "[XYZ Effect](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Xyz_Effect)"  activated?

Answer (score 2):

> Does XYZ Effect resolve?

**In all scenarios you mention XYZ Effect resolves**

Why? Because **neither MST, Cosmic Cyclone, or that card that returns to deck have the ability to negate effects;** they "just" destroy the card, but never negated its activation and thus it resolves.

This situation is similar to one [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/40535/22373) I gave recently. The only cases where a card like MST or similar (that just destroys) can prevent a spell/trap card effect from activating is if that spell/trap card has a continuous effect.

For example, if your opponent activates [Fire Formation - Tenki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Formation_-_Tenki) and you cast MST on it your opponent will not be able to search for a beast-warrior. This is because **cards with continuous effects must remain face-up on the field to resolve their effects.**

Comment: field spells also need to remain to resolve their effects

Comment: @Whatsthepoimt yep, as stated on the other answer :)